# Bridge fails to run

Tags: bridge

I changed my perfectly running relay of 30 days to a bridge.
That's when the problems started.

Running as usr

tor --verify-config
Configuration is valid

systemctl start tor.service
Pass entered - no complaints

After roughly a minute -

systemctl status tor@default
Active: failed[image: Systemctl Status]

What are the last two lines tying to tell me??

Process: 2486 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/tor --defaults-torrc /usr/share/tor/tor-service-defaults-torrc -f /etc/tor/torrc --RunAsDaemon 0 --verify-config

Process: 2485 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/install -Z -m 02755 -o debian-tor -g debian-tor -d /run/tor (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

adriann

Comment: please send an output of `journalctl -feu tor@default.service` - it will contain the full logs

Answer (score 0):

Which ports are you using ? Do you use pluggable-transport like obfs4 ?

https://community.torproject.org/relay/setup/bridge/debian-ubuntu/

Comment: SocksPort 0
Log notice file /var/log/tor/notices.log
XXLog debug file /var/log/tor/debug.log
DataDirectory /var/lib/tor
RunAsDaemon 0
ControlPort 9051
ORPort 6969
Address 192.xx.xx.xxx
Nickname XXXXXXX
RelayBandwidthRate 1.29 MB
RelayBandwidthBurst 2 MB
ContactInfo XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.com
BridgeRelay 1
ServerTransportPlugin obfs4 exec /usr/bin/obfs4proxy
ServerTransportListenAddr obfs4 0.0.0.0:8989
ExtORPort auto
CookieAuthentication 1

Comment: FWIW I used the above link to initially set up the bridge - adriann